# Python function does not run

Tags: python

So I created a function called calculator, which takes the celsius parameter.

I tried using raw_input instead of input, but it didnt work.I also tried replacing return with print, but no result.

```
def calculator(celsius):
    celsius = float(input())
    fahrenheit = celsius * 9 / 5 + 32
    print(fahrenheit)
calculator()
```

It should take the user's input in Celsius degrees, and then conver it into fahrenheit degrees and print them.

Comment: Your function requires an argument, but you called it without one.  This is a syntax error.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
"it didn't work" is not a problem specification.

Comment: @Prune ^TypeError...

Comment: Simply delete the argument from your function's definition

Comment: @Prune that is not a syntax error, just to be pedantic. The syntax is fine, it's the semantics that cause an issue

Comment: Yes, it's a TypeError.

Comment: Not a syntax error and there was no reason for the downvote since it isn't a low quality question. The user is just very new to python.

Answer (score 2):

Fix your syntax error, use the correct type and your code works...

```
def calculator(celsius):
  if(celsius.isdigit()):
    celsius = float(celsius)
    fahrenheit = celsius * 9 / 5 + 32
    print(fahrenheit)

Temp = input("Enter temperature: ")

calculator(Temp)
```